# Como faço para usar a tag symbol no lugar da tag g no iron-iconset-svg?

Tags: svg, polymer

Estou tentando definir um iron-iconset-svg usando usando os ícones com a tag symbol ao invés de usar a tag g e o ícone não é renderizado. Em toda documentação e referências na internet o SVG é usado com a tag g. Existe

Segue trecho do código:

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="br-icons">
  <svg style="display: none">
    <defs>    
      <symbol id="icon-menu" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
        <title>menu</title>
        <path class="path1" d="M64 192h896v192h-896zM64 448h896v192h-896zM64 704h896v192h-896z"></path>
      </symbol>
    </defs>
  </svg>
 </iron-iconset-svg>
```

Segue a chamada ao componente:

```
<iron-icon icon="br-icons:icon-menu"></iron-icon>
```

Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A utilização da tag `<symbol>` exige a reutilização do ícone utilizando a tag `<use>`. Dessa forma, na atual versão do polymer o `iron-iconset-svg` funciona somente com a utilização da tag `<g>`.

Answer (score 0):

Cara acredito que seria um pouco mais simples:

```
    <!-- Seu componente aqui -->
    <svg style="display:none" id="my-icons">

    <!-- Elementos de seu componente --> 
      <symbol id="icon-1"><path d="coord..."> </symbol>
      <symbol id="icon-2"><path d="coord..."> </symbol>
      <symbol id="icon-3"><path d="coord..."> </symbol>

    </svg>

<!-- chamando seu componente -->
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="x y w h">

<!-- passando o ID -->
     <use xlink:href="#icon-1"></use> 
    </svg>
```

Comment: Quando faço isso dentro do componente só funciona se eu passar o id do ícone direto. No caso eu estou passando ele via atributo do componente.

      <use xlink:href$="{{icon}}"></use>

Ele renderiza o id no html mas não exibe o ícone

Comment: @cbfranca Se ele injeta id no html menos mal, verifica se na tag <use></use> você está colocando as coordenadas X e Y. Ex: <use xlink:href="#icon-1" x="10" y ="40"></use>, acredito que ele precise dessa referência para mostrar o elemento.

Comment: Não estou passando não, mas, se entendi corretamente, seria 0,0 nesse caso:

     <symbol id="icon-menu" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">

Comment: O estranho é que se eu passar o id do ícone direto ele funciona. Mas se eu passar via atributo do polymer n funciona.

 <svg>
    <use xlink:href$="{{icon}}" x="0" y="0"></use>
  </svg>

  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#icon-user" x="0" y="0"></use>
  </svg>

Comment: Tire o atributo viewBox da tag <symbol> e deixe somente para o container svg dos elementos, como no código acima. Se você fez o teste colocando o id direto e funcionou não há razões para não renderizar uma vez que você recupera esse mesmo valor e joga para o atributo id de seu elemento id== "valor de id" -> {{valor injetado}}

Comment: Nada. Está me parecendo ser algo relacionado ao polymer mesmo. Estou pesquisando aqui mas não achei nada relativo.